# AngularJS Directive to read current templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I've written some logic within my Controllers to insert my apps meta-data:

**HTML:**

```
html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController"

meta name="description" content="{{ seo.metaDescription }}"
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "page1.html",
            controller: "Page1Controller"
        })
        .when("/ledlighting", {
            templateUrl: "page2.html",
            controller: "Page2Controller"
        })
        // .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
        ;
}]);
app.controller('MainController', ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.seo = { 
        metaDescription : ''
    }; 

}]);
app.controller('Page1Controller', ["$scope", function($scope) {

    console.log("Greetings from controller 1");

    $scope.$parent.seo = { 
        metaDescription: 'My SEO Meta Description'
    };

}]);
```

The above works fine, however, rather than having to write the SEO values in each controller, can I write a directive? Can directives determine which/what the current route is?

Essentially I want to replace my meta tags with directives and insert content/descriptions based on the current route.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directive I would suggest simpler approach: to read route configuration seo information directly.

For this you need to store seo data in route config:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "page1.html",
        controller: "Page1Controller",
        seo: {
            metaDescription: "My SEO Meta Description"
        }
    })
```

and then in run block of your application you can add `$routeChangeSuccess` event listener that would set `$rootScope.seo` based on current `$route`:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (oldVal !== newVal) {
            $rootScope.seo = $route.current.seo;
        }
    });
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fzm6FknfOO8I6vdAO39g?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense and is a simple solution. IF i need to go down the directive route, how could that be achieved?

Comment: Well you *could* write a directive but it makes less sense. This is not job for directive in this case. Check one possible directive solution. http://plnkr.co/edit/6OoIvw1dGvp57Nz31Kt0?p=preview

Comment: Is your second link correct? Doesn't seem to be a directive version.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, hadnt refreshed my browser. Makes sense, however id take the values out of the controller and try to create a properties var within the directive??

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using controllers in this case at all. They are not for data and business logic. Either use services or route configs like I posted.

Comment: I agree. im trying to find a way to not store the seo data in the Controllers or Route configs... Directive was my first thought as its a line that can be copied an pasted as a opposed to a service as a service would have to be called from each Controller.